# laravel - do I have to set withPivot fields on both models?

Tags: php, laravel

I need some fields (SCORE, HEALTH) in many-to-many relation.

Models

```
Channel => title
Company => id
```

Tables

```
channels         => id, title
companies        => id
company_channel  => channel_id, company_id, SCORE, HEALTH
```

The question is: do I have to set withPivot fields on both models?

```
// channel model
public function companies() { return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Company')->withPivot(['score', 'health']); }

// company model
public function channels() { return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Channel')->withPivot(['score', 'health']); }
```

Comment: Yes, there isn't a way laravel can figure that out on its own

Comment: You don't have to, it will work regardless, it mostly depends if you need to access those values or not, perhaps you only need those pivot values for the channels relation, and if so you don't need withPivot on the companies relation. You can also choose to set it everywhere for consistency, it's how you prefer. But in the end the relation will work in both cases.